# Are there any downsides of having a 99default_release in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d

Tags: debian, apt

Instead of having `/etc/apt/preferences` file. I made the following -

```
$ cat 99default_release 
APT::Default-Release "testing";
```

The following is the `/etc/apt/sources.list` -

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

       #### Debian buster #########
        deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

       #### Debian unstable #########
    deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free

        #### Debian experimental #########
    deb http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib
    deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib

       ##### Debian Debug packages #######
    deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ buster-debug main
    deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ unstable-debug main
    deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ experimental-debug main

      ######## Third party repos #######
    deb https://riot.im/packages/debian/ stretch main
    deb https://lxqt.debian.net/debian  experimental-snapshots  main
    deb-src https://lxqt.debian.net/debian  experimental-snapshots  main
```

It does seem to do the job -

```
$ apt-cache policy 
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://lxqt.debian.net/debian experimental-snapshots/main amd64 Packages
     release o=lxqt,n=experimental-snapshots,c=main,b=amd64
     origin lxqt.debian.net
 990 https://riot.im/packages/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release o=riot.im,a=testing,n=stretch,c=main,b=amd64
     origin riot.im
   1 http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug experimental-debug/main amd64 Packages
```

The only 'gotchas' I probably need to think about is when buster hits release is renaming the `99default_release` to buster and not removing unstable repository for a month or two .

Am I missing something else ?

I know it's still a long road to freeze and then release

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster

probably 2-3 months after full freeze or if we are lucky then less than that.

Comment: If your plan is to track Buster after its release, then you might as well specify that right now — `APT::Default-Release "buster";`. That way you don’t need to remember to do anything after release.